# By default django saves UTC time into DB, I am trying to change it to IST timezone

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, rdbms, django-timezone

Whenever a datetime field is updated it saves UTC time in DB. The problem is the DB I am using is used by multiple other applications/technologies. Other applications are using IST time to save the datetime. However coming to Django it saves the datetime to DB in UTC  only.

I am looking to force Django to save datetime in IST (local time-zone).

using Django 3.2